# Removing substring of from a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

There are several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in my list. How I  remove these?

e.g.

'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be **'Bolivia'**,

'Switzerland17' should be **'Switzerland**'.

Answer (score 1):

Run just:

```
df.Country.replace(r'\d+|\s*\([^)]*\)', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Assuming that the initial content of your DataFrame is:

```
                            Country
0  Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
1                     Switzerland17
2                    United Kingdom
```

after the above *replace* you will have:

```
          Country
0         Bolivia
1     Switzerland
2  United Kingdom
```

The above pattern contains:

- the first alternative - a non-empty sequence of digits,
- the second alternative:

  - an optional sequence of "white" chars,
  - an opening parenthesis (quoted),
  - a sequence of chars other than `)` (between brackets no quotation is
    needed),
  - a closing parenthesis (also quoted).

Comment: Construct like ".*" in the pattern is likely to consume either too little or too much. So if you want to match content e.g. between parentheses, then the "inside" part should match characters **other** than ")".

Comment: In ".*" there is **greedy** matching, so the regex processor attemts to match as many chars as possible (up to the end of string or the current line) and then "moves back" char by char. Such way of operation slows down the whole matching. But if you match characters other than ")" you will stop much earlier. This is a very basic rule concerning how to write or not to write regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex for replacement, `\s*` is for possible spaces before `(`, then `\(.*\)` is for values `()` and values between `|` is for regex `or` and `\d+` is for numbers with 1 or more digits:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17']})

df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('(\s*\(.*\)|\d+)','')
print (df)
             a
0      Bolivia
1  Switzerland
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove string by this way:-

Remove numbers:-

```
import re
a = 'Switzerland17'
pattern = '[0-9]'
res = re.sub(pattern, '', a)
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
'Switzerland'
```

Remove parenthesis:-

```
b = 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)'
pattern2 = '(\s*\(.*\))'
res2 = re.sub(pattern2, '', b)
print(res2)
```

Output:-

```
'Bolivia'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Regex and simple List Operation**

Go through the list items, find the regex matching in each item, and replace the values in place. This regex **"[a-zA-Z]{2,}"** works for only string matching with the minimum size of two or more. It gives your freedom based on **parenthesis**. The better approach for Regex is to use Matching string based on your input domain (i.e country in your case) and a Country name cannot have a number in its name or Parenthesis. SO you should use the following.

```
import re 
list_of_country_strings = ["Switzerland17", "America290","Korea(S)"]
for index in range(len(list_of_country_strings)):
    x = re.match("[a-zA-Z]{2,}",string = list_of_country_strings[index])
    if x:
        list_of_country_strings[index] = list_of_country_strings[index][x.start():x.end()]

print(list_of_country_strings)
```

**Output**
['Switzerland', 'America', 'Korea']